# How can I accomplish this design with flexbox?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to accomplish this design by using flexbox:

[image]

It's supposed to be a one page website.

```css
  .container {
      display: flex;
    }

    .big {
      flex: 2;
      height: 70vh;
      background: gray;
    }

    .small {
      flex: 1;
      height: 70vh;
      background: gray;
    }
```

```html
<div class="container">
      <div class="small">
      </div>
      <div class="smallest">
      </div>
      <div class="big">
      </div>
 </div>
```

I have no idea how to implement the "smallest" div to be 25% of the big, let alone make the "small" 75% of the big one.

Also the height really confuses me, I need them to always have the same height.

Answer (score 4):

With flexbox you can *wrap* the `small` and the `smallest` into a separate div and use *column flexbox* on the `left` section.

> I have no idea how to implement the "smallest" div to be 25% of the big

25% to 75% ratio means 1:3 ratio - and in *flexbox* language that is `flex: 1` to the *small element* and `flex: 3` to the *big element*.

> Also the height really confuses me, I need them to always have the same height.

You can set the height of the container to the `container` element - your flexbox will fill to this height.

See demo below:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  height: 70vh;
}

.big {
  flex: 3;
  background: gray;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.left {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.left .small {
  background: gray;
  flex: 3;
}

.left .smallest {
  margin-top: 5px;
  background: gray;
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">
    <div class="small">
    </div>
    <div class="smallest">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="big">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Many many thanks! Incredible how fast you solved this for me!